# How to deploy a script to auto update google chrome on a lot of hp thin clients?

Tags: hp, deployment, shell-scripting, google-chrome, thin-client

The hurdle is that the thin client wipes and re-images itself every night and I have no access to group policy. Any ideas of deployment or the most efficient way to do this?

What I do have access to is the following:

- Landesk - a program to connect to most of our computers
- TightVNC - Access to the few that are not on Landesk
- Ability to save files in the image so it doesn't wipe

Comment: HP has the HPDM device management software. That’s the right way to handle.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I recently gained access to my companies HPDM and im learning how to use it currently. Now i just need to push it out and make it force update using a script. I havent found any powershell scripts online to do this so im stuck trying to write it myself.